# Data Source Connection in Windows Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio

I try to write a Windows Forms Application, which should have a Data Source connection. I tried it for at least two hours now, but I don't get it. I tried to use a DataSet or a Service-based Database, but I don't know how to get access to the data.
I know how to set up my tables, that is not the problem.

I want to read/update/insert to my tables through the C# code without using SQL Commands. Is there an example code or tutorial anywhere?

I'm using SQL Server Express 2014 and Visual Studio Community 2015.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Entity Framework to work with Database without writing SQL connection and commands. I recommen you this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners and this book http://www.apress.com/9781430226536

Comment: Working, thanks :)